# Laravel 5.2 Update Record

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm doing a simple CRUD. I have problem with editing and updating the record in the database.

This is my route.php:

```
Route::post('/task/edit',function (Request $request, $id){
$task = Task::find($id);
$task->name = Input::get('name');
$task->save();

return redirect('/');
});
```

This is my form:

```
<form action="{{url('/task/edit')}}" method="POST" role="form">
  {{csrf_field()}}
  <label for="editTask" class="control-label">Edit Task</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name">
  <br>
  <button class="btn btn-success form-control">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Can I know how to fix this? I was referring to [Basic Task List](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/quickstart) and wanted to add one more function which is update. Or did I just do something completely wrong?

Comment: And your problem is?!

Comment: you don't specifiy id parameter in your route...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
Route::post('/task/edit', function (Request $request){

    $task = Task::find($request->input('id'));
    $task->name = $request->input('name');
    $task->save();

    return redirect('/');
});
```

and in the form you must add an input type hidden

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $id }}" />
```

and don't forget to place those routes inside the

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {...});
```

in order for _token to work

Comment: Glad to hear that, yw.

Comment: I have another problem now, so right now I have a few data, but whenever I try to edit a particular data, only the first data is edited. How can I fix this?

Comment: [here](http://laravel.io/bin/523nG), somehow my validation is not working anymore whem I don't enter any text the form, but the error message is not appearing.

Comment: If you don't provide me with the actual code how can I tell what's wrong? Show me the validation rules, the code that makes the validation and the code from blade where you're displaying the error messages. Maybe even the entire method, or at least the relevant part.

Comment: First of all you're missing  value="{{$task->name}}" in the input name="name", so make it to <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{$task->name}}" />

Comment: It's pretty hard for me to spot the problems since you're using some modals in there, but as I see you're not using the validation inside the /task/edit route, so you can't expect to have validation errors on edit/update

Comment: Yes, I modified that and it is still the same.
The error message is fixed by editing the Kernel.php.

Comment: Sorry but you lost me with this one: "The error message is fixed by editing the Kernel.php".

Comment: Forgot to mention that the error message is used to add new entry, it is not part of editing data.

Comment: Initially you said this:
"I have another problem now, so right now I have a few data, but whenever I try to edit a particular data, only the first data is edited. How can I fix this"

Comment: Sorry, to clear that out, the error message/ validation is used to add new entry whereas the editing part is just like what you mentioned back to me.

Comment: It's working here, take a look: http://imgur.com/hQISYVV I suspect that your problem has to do with the modal. Are the errors in the parent window?

Comment: Yes it is in the parent window and it is fixed by editing Kernel.php like I mentioned just now. It is fixed by moving 
`\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,` 
and
`\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,`
from middleware group to middleware in Kernel.php

Comment: And now, in the editing part, for instance, I have 5 data, no matter which data I am trying to edit, it is always the first data getting edited.

Comment: I realized that no matter which data I clicked to edit, the $task->name in the textbox of the modal is always the first data. Is this because of modal?

Comment: Yes, definitely. I guess that in the modal you will always have the first item from the iteration/loop. You have to load the correct data on modal open. This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25261877/using-bootstrap-modal-with-a-foreach-loop